# Why is Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor still referencing Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage?

Tags: azure, .net-core, storage, azure-eventhub

Building for dotnet core 2.2

I include the following:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;             (4.0.0)
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor;   (4.0.0)
```

I am throwing an exception trying to do:

```
_eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(
               hubName,
               PartitionReceiver.DefaultConsumerGroupName,
               _eventHubConnectionString,
               _storageConnectionString,
               blobName);
```

The exception says:

"Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'"

When I look at the stub, I can indeed see that various constructors for EventProcessorHost do reference members from the old namespace -- such as Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.

My understanding was that the old space Microsoft.WindowsAzure had been entirely replaced by the new space Microsoft.Azure.  Do I still need to import the old space?

Tried installing Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Common, uninstalling and re-installing the WindowsAzure libraries.

Comment: which version of the EventHub nuget package do you reference?

Comment: I am using 4.0.0

Comment: Hm at least based on the Nuget page it shouldn't reference WindowsAzure... anymore

Comment: See source here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor/src/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor.csproj

Comment: I downloaded the source you reference.

In \eventhub\Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor you can see that WindowsAzure is included:

namespace Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Primitives;
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

   ......
}

Comment: ok see my answer below. I think I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 0822**:

This seams to be a bug in the 4.0.0 version of Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor, there is an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/7305) to track it. Currently, you can use 3.0.0 version for your purpose.

And as well, I followed this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send#receive-events) to test event hub receiver, using 4.0.0 package for both `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` and `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor`, it works fine at my side. And the default installed storage sdk is `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`, version 9.4.2.

Note: As you can see, there 5 constructors of EventProcessorHost, please use the first one which uses string type for all the parameters.

[image]

The test result:

[image]

---

Please try to use the latest version `4.0.0` of nuget Package [Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor/4.0.0), it uses the new version of storage sdk like `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`. Screenshot as below:

[image]

The other version prior to 4.0.0, like 3.0.0 / 2.2.1 are still using the old storage sdk like `WindowsAzure.Storage`.

Comment: Yes, I am using 4.0.0

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this! -- I'll give the 3.0.0 downgrade a try tonight and let you know.

Comment: @MichaelDavidArner, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: I have done so.  My reputation is still low, so they're not publicly displaying it.
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @MichaelDavidArner, regarding how to mark as answer(not vote-up), you can follow this [guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). What you did before is vote-up, not mark as answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured out your actual "issue" now:

Even though version 4.0.0 of the EventHubsProcessorHost nuget package already uses the new nuget package `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob`, only in the new versions (since 10.0) of that package, the namespace has changed from `Microsoft.WindowsAzure...` to `Microsoft.Azure...`. I could not see yet which exact version of the storage library the EHProcessorHost is using, it looks like it's one < 10.0.0.

See here for the changelog of the storage library:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Blob/BreakingChanges.txt

> Tracking Breaking Changes since 10.0:
>
> - Namespace change from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.* to Microsoft.Azure.Storage.*, required for SxS with pre-9.4 versions of
>     the library.

Comment: So, should it be sufficient to add the latest version of Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob? Doing so just updates the version in the same error message:

"Could not load type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'."

Comment: It looks as if they did not have the breaking dependency up until 9....and it's still breaking at 11?